# Create Context issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, createcontext

I have a **Search.jsx** file where I take the username as input from the user. I want to pass the username to the rest of my project, so I decided to use a context. However, I am encountering an issue where I'm getting an **undefined** value when I try to access the username in other files using the context. When I console log it, it shows as undefined. Below are my files :-

**Search.jsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import { Box, IconButton, InputBase } from '@mui/material';

const SearchContext = createContext();

export default function Search() {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(searchQuery);
    };

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <SearchContext.Provider value={searchQuery}>
            <Box display='flex' alignItems='center' justifyContent='center' paddingTop='20px'>
                <Paper component="form" sx={{ p: '2px 10px', display: 'flex', width: '50%' }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <IconButton type="button" sx={{ p: '10px' }} aria-label="search">
                        <AccountCircleIcon fontSize='large' />
                    </IconButton>
                    <InputBase
                        sx={{ ml: 1, flex: 1 }}
                        placeholder="Search User"
                        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search user' }}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <IconButton type="submit" sx={{ p: '10px' }} aria-label="search">
                        <SearchIcon fontSize='large' />
                    </IconButton>
                </Paper>
            </Box>
        </SearchContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { SearchContext };
```

*File Where I'm trying to get the data*

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ApiService } from '../../API/ApiService';
import { SearchContext } from '../../Search/Search';

function NumberOfContestParticipated({ handle }) {
    const [contestCount, setContestCount] = useState(null);
    const searchQuery = useContext(SearchContext);
    console.log(searchQuery);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const ratingUrl = `https://codeforces.com/api/user.rating?handle=${handle}`;
            const ratingData = await ApiService(ratingUrl);

            if (ratingData && ratingData.status === 'OK') {
                setContestCount(ratingData.result.length);
            } else {
                setContestCount(0);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [handle]);

    return (
        <div>
            {contestCount !== null ? (
                <p>Number of contests participated by {handle}: {contestCount}</p>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default NumberOfContestParticipated;
```

I'm getting undefined when I console log searchQuery.

**Index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { SearchContext } from './Search/Search';

ReactDOM.render(
  <SearchContext.Provider>
    <App />
  </SearchContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Is `NumberOfContestParticipated` a child of `Search`?. Context providers must be parents to its consumers [docs](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

Comment: Yes, it is the child of Search